# SharePoint Integration with Team Foundation Server

Tags: iis, sharepoint, installation, team-foundation-server

I am attemping to get SharePoint Portal integrations on Team Foundation Server 2010 x86 running with a standard single server installation on a WinServer w SP2. I can provide any and all information but I believe there is a permissions issue somewhere.

Error:

[2012-08-06 23:23:54Z][Error] TF252031: A SharePoint site could not be created for the team project collection. The following error occurred: TF250034: An access grant could not be found between Team Foundation Server and the SharePoint Web application that you specified. The Team Foundation Server ID is: db1d4655-f543-4709-b8e9-306410088558. The SharePoint Web application is:         'http://prod01/sites/test6.'

You must grant access for the Web application in the Team Foundation Administration Console.
I also noticed in the Central Administration site there is a server service, "Windows SharePoint Services Search ", not running. When trying to start the service I'm directed to a service configuration page that I have filled 100x using domain credentials for the service account (same username for both the service account and the content access account, windows authentication for the SQL account)

I receive the following error:

"Error SPSearch (_tfssvcprod) Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services. "
which is not particularly helpful. I am not sure how to proceed at this point.

Comment: I am resposting this question from SharePoint StackExchange because I am not sure the problem is related to SharePoint specifically. It seems more of an IIS issue.

Comment: You should not repost questions across the stack exchange network.  If you feel it is better suited on another site simply ask a moderator to move it for you.

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions. If a question should be on another site we can migrate it; if you want it to be moved please flag it for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty much tells you what you have to do:

> You must grant access for the Web application in the Team Foundation Administration Console

The Search Service is simply a search indexer and provider and has nothing to do with TFS.

Here is the relevant page on MSDN for how to grant access to the Web app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236907